# can i use an ubuntu live usb/cd without damaging my windows 8 pc?

Tags: boot, windows, usb

I have a windows 8 laptop with intel i3 and 750gb hard drive.
I don't want to install Ubuntu instead of windows and have heard horror stories about only being able to have one system on the hard drive because Microsoft have prevented partitioning or something like that. Can I run Ubuntu from a live USB stick or external hard drive without damaging windows?
thanks

Comment: You can install Ubuntu in your system. Just follow this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, aslong as you don't install ubuntu/edit partitions you are fine.
The live version just loads itself into your ram, and runs. You can however install programs on the ubuntu live version, it will be written to your ram too. Just don't install ubuntu/repartition your harddrive.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful. I din't want to break my pc with dabbling.

Comment: Just press Try ubuntu first, and not install ;).

Comment: You can actually install stuff, it will just install to ram, or if you have persistence enabled on your usb it will save your changes to usb.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but I meant install with install ubuntu, I will update that, thanks.